# ActiveMQ Web Console only listens on localhost

Tags: jetty, activemq-classic

I've got ActiveMQ installed as I want it. However, the Web Console only listens on localhost - how do I make it listen on all interfaces? I'm sure it's a "host"="0.0.0.0" somewhere but where?

Comment: Questions like this which are less about programming and more about server administration & configuration belong on a site like ServerFault rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the latest versions of ActiveMQ (e.g. 5.5), you can configure within the `<activemq>/conf/jetty.xml` file by adding a `host` property setting to the `SelectChannelConnector` bean.

```
<bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
    **<property name="host" value="0.0.0.0"/>**
    <property name="port" value="8161" />
</bean>
```

Looking at the `SelectChannelConnector` code, if the `host` property is not set (i.e. `null`) then it will use the default for `InetSocketAddress`, which is supposed to be the "wildcard address" per the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html), so I'm surprised its not automatically binding to all addresses on your server by default.

Hope that helps,

Scott

[FuseSource](http://fusesource.com/)

Comment: Hi Scott - I'm using the latest from the site. I'll make the change as suggested. Thanks very much!